# Set same height across different divs issue

Tags: jquery, height, equals

I have this piece of script which figures out the div with the largest height, and sets it to all other divs of my seletion. Which works pretty awesome. The problem though is, this method seems to include hidden divs (to calculate the height). Is this a known thing? I tried adding a filter (:visible) to no avail.

```
var windowWidth = $j(window).width();
$j.fn.setAllToMaxHeight = function() {
    return this.height(Math.max.apply(this, $j.map(this.children().filter(':visible'), function(e) { 
        return $j(e)[0].scrollHeight;
    })));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you might want to write it like this:

```
$j.map(this.filter($j('> :visible', this))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var maxHeight = -1;
$('div').each(function() {
    if ($('div').is(':visible') && $('div').height() > maxHeight)
    maxHeight = $(this).height();
});
$('div').each(function() {
    $(this).height(maxHeight);
});
```